# VBA If condition with .TintAndShade

Tags: vba, if-statement

What would the VBA code look like if I want to put the value of a cell from one row below to the cell above only if the above cell is for ex.

```
.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
```

[image]

my code won't work:

```
Sub Macro1()
If ActiveCell.Interior.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314 Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service.  Have a go yourself.  If it doesn't work come back with your code and any error messages you encountered.

Comment: Code added - it does nothing actually, no error msg.

Comment: Your code lacks a loop.  You need to process the cells in Excel one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code lacks a loop.  This will allow you to process each row individually.  I've used a [FOR...NEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) but you could also use a [WHILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1f56zs.aspx) or a [DO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx).  Each of these allows you repeat an action as many times as required.  FORs are good for a set number of iterations.  DO and WHILE are useful when there is an exit condition to check for.

```
Sub Macro1()
Const COLUMN As Integer = 1         ' 1 for A, 2 for B, etc.
Dim row As Integer


    ' Will process the first hundred rows of column A.
    For row = 1 To 100

        If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, COLUMN).Interior.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314 Then

            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, COLUMN).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 1, COLUMN).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This code is ok but it could be better.  The number of rows to loop over is currently hard coded.  One way to improve this is by using the [UsedRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) object to calculate the number of rows required.

Comment: My code was just an example applicable to the ActiveCell. I would add the loop later if the code worked. Your code does nothing, just like mine. Nothing happens.

Comment: I think the problem is with TintAndShade.  I can't get Excel to accept the value of .799...314.  I may be using a different theme to you.  Can you try setting the background colour to pure red and update TintAndShade to `ActiveCell.Interior.Color = rgb(255,0,0)`.

Comment: Yes, it works with `ActiveCell.Interior.Color`. Thank You for Your help.